# Javascript adding styling to element with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am making a dropdown menu in a dropdown, I want that I have a few head items and if you click on one, the dropdown in that head item is displayed as a block element. But the problem is that they all have the same class and when I want to add a class all the dropdowns inside the head items get that class. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var click = false;
        jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li").click(function() {
    
            if(click == false) {
                jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li ul").addClass('clicked');
                click = true;
            } else {
                jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li ul").removeClass('clicked');
                click = false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
    .clicked {
        display: block !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav menu">
        <li class="item-101 default deeper parent">
               <a href="/">Home</a>
               <ul class="nav-child unstyled small clicked">
                  <li class="item-124">
                      <a href="/home/maandmail">Maandmail</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="item-102 default deeper parent">
               <a href="/">Contact</a>
               <ul class="nav-child unstyled small clicked">
                  <li class="item-125">
                      <a href="/home/contact-page">Contact pagina</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe try jQuery(this).find('ul').first() or $(this).find('ul').first() to add and remove class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the code look at the specific UL relative to the item you've clicked on:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var click = false;
  jQuery(".navbar-collapse .nav li").click(function(e) {
    if (click == false) {
      jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("ul").addClass('clicked');
      click = true;
    } else {
      jQuery(e.currentTarget).find("ul").removeClass('clicked');
      click = false;
    }
  });
});
```